# Laravel Muchos a muchos 2 niveles table pivote

Tags: laravel

Tengo las siguientes tabla

Tabla Actividad

```
Schema::create('activities', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('actividad')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Tabla Area

```
Schema::create('areas', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('area')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

y la primera tabla Pivote activity_areas

```
Schema::create('activity_areas', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();

    $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_activity')->nullable();
    $table->foreign('id_activity')->references('id')->on('activities');

    $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_area')->nullable();
    $table->foreign('id_area')->references('id')->on('areas');

    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Modelo activityArea

```
class activityArea extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function activity()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(activity::class, 'id_activity');
    }

    public function area()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(area::class, 'id_area');
    }
}
```

Tengo una segunda tabla Pivote llamada tasks

```
Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('id_activity_area')->nullable();
    $table->foreign('id_activity_area')->references('id')->on('activity_areas');
    $table->string('task')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

tengo controlador tasks

```
class TaskView extends Component
{
    public function render()
    {    
        $tasks = task::get();

        return view('livewire.task-view', compact('tasks'));
    }
}
```

Vista tasks

```
<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
            <div class="h3">Tareas</div>
            <table class="table table-Dark table-vcenter text-center">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">#</th>
                        <th scope="col">id_activity_area</th>
                        <th scope="col">task</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach ($tasks as $item)
                        <tr>
                            <td> {{ $item->id }}</td>
                            <td> {{ $item->id_activity_area }}</td>
                            <td> {{ $item->task }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

En la tabla Tareas en el campo id_activity_area no quiero el ID de la actividad_area sino los datos correspondientes a esa relación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en el campo actividad_area

- 1 remplazar por Actividad 1 - Area 3
- 2 remplazar por Actividad 2 - Area 1
- 3 remplazar por Actividad 3 - Area 2

E visto varios tutoriales como [este](https://www.mejorcodigo.com/p/104868.html) pero no e podido terminar ni adatar el proyecto que tengo, le agradecería si me pueden ayudar a resolver el inconveniente.

---

Solución Completa

Lo primero, como ya tenia la relación en el modelo **activityArea** lo que hice fue, en modelo **task** hacer una relación hacia el modelo **activityArea** de la siguiente manera

```
class task extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function idactivityarea()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(activityAarea::class, 'id_activity_area');
    }
}
```

El controlador no hice ninguna modificación.

En la Vista Task quedo de la siguiente manera

```
@foreach ($tasks as $item)
    <tr>
        <td> {{ $item->id }}</td>
        <td> {{ $item->id_activity_area }}</td>
        <td> {{ $item->idactivityarea->activity->actividad}} - 
             {{ $item->idactivityarea->area->area }} </td>
        <td> {{ $item->task }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

quedando el siguiente resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cabe recalcar que  **{{ $item->id_activity_area }}** lo deje para verificar la relación

Todo el crédito para **@HeytalePazguato** que me ayudo con su respuesta

Comment: Buen día, en tu controlador `tasks` ¿Dónde estas definiendo la relación con tu tabla `activity_area`?

Comment: no te definidas mas relaciones, si me indicas que debo de hacer te lo agradezco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Si lo que quieres es acceder a `area` y `Actividad` desde `tarea` lo que puedes hacer en tu `@foreach` es lo siguiente:

```
@foreach ($tasks as $item)
    <tr>
        <td> {{ $item->id }}</td>
        <td> {{ $item->id_activity_area->id_activity->actividad }}</td>
        <td> {{ $item->id_activity_area->id_area->area}}</td>
        <td> {{ $item->task }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

De esta forma no modificas tus tablas

Pero si deseas que en tu segunda tabla pivote aparezcan área y actividad entonces podrías agregar otras 2 columnas y crear métodos para que directamente se escriba el valor de tu relación

En mi opinión, tal como la tienes ahora es funcional a nivel base de datos y puedes acceder a la información a través de los métodos donde defines las relaciones, recuerda que todas las relaciones funcionan como "generadores de consulta"

Un tip extra, usa `php artisan tinker` para comprobar la información que puedes acceder en cada elemento, por ejemplo:

1. En tu consola escribe `php artisan tinker` (Tienes que estar dentro de tu carpeta de tu proyecto en laravel, puedes usar shell o si usas Visual Studio Code puedes hacerlo a través de la consola integrada)
2. Accede al primer elemento en tu segunda tabla pivote (Si es que ya tienes elementos, si no debes crearlos) `$tarea = Task::first()` (No pones el nombre de tu modelo para tareas así que asumo que se llama "Task")
3. Accede al método de `$tarea` donde tienes tu relación (No lo mencionas, asumo que se llama "getActivityAreaId") `$tarea->getActivityAreaId` (Esto te va a mostrar la información de tu tabla `activity_area`
4. Accede al método que define tu relación con la tabla `activity` para que te muestre la información de esa tabla `$tarea->getActivityAreaId->id_activity`
5. Puedes seguir de esa forma hasta encontrar la actividad `$tarea->getActivityAreaId->id_activity->actividad`

Probando con tinker te vas a ahorrar muchos dolores de cabeza

Comment: buenos dias, gracias por tu respuesta, pero para poder acceder a {{ $item->id_activity_area->id_area->area}} tengo que hacer algo en los modelos, por que coloque la linea y me marca el siguiente error https://flareapp.io/share/95JKWwym#F69

Comment: Como mencioné en el paso 3, debes utilizar el método de tu relación entre la tabla `tasks` y la tabla `activity_area` tal como hiciste en `activityArea` donde tienes tus métodos `area()` y `activity()` que utilizan `belongsTo`. No sé si tus tareas tengan relación uno a muchos, muchos a muchos, etc... pero debes crear un método que cree tu relación entre `tasks` y `activity_area`, si no lo haces entonces `activity_area` es únicamente un entero y por eso te sale ese error

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda ya me funciono, agrege en el modelo task     public function idactivityarea()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(activityAarea::class, 'id_activity_area');
    } ---- y la linea {{ $item->idactivityarea->activity->actividad}} para acceder a la información. corrugué el ejemplo para que te quede bien la respuesta

Comment: Buen día @YamidCano, que bueno que ya funcionó. Por cierto, no es necesario que el ejemplo quede exactamente igual a lo que tú pusiste en tu código después de leer el ejemplo. Una recomendación más, se aconseja que los métodos sigan el estilo CamelCase (La primera letra de cada palabra en mayúsculas para leerlo mejor, la primera palabra puede ir con minúsculas) por lo que tú método sería mejor `idActivityArea`. Si la respuesta te sirvió no olvides aceptarla, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a problemas similares y ayudas a la comunidad a tener abiertas preguntas sin solución